# Changed text not posting back to code-behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox on an ASP.NET 4.0 page.  I can add text to the textbox in the code-behind and when the page renders, the text displays just fine.  However, when I modify the textbox in the browser and submit the page, the MyTextBox.Text property still shows the original text and not the modifed text I entered in the browser.  How can the code-behind show the modified text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for a postback in your initial textbox, like this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   MyTextBox.Text = "This is the text when page renders";
}
```

You can set your textbox normally in the code behind for the submit button handler.

```
void SubmitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBox.Text = tbUserInputHere.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you took care of the page's `IsPostBack` condition properly.

You have to assign it a value like...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "You Text"
    }
```

You are assigning a value in the `page load event` and when you click the button, the page load is called before the `Click event handler` and your value will be reset to the old value.